# Why can't I compare the angle I found, using \tkzFindAngle, to 180?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I am practicing with the `tkz-euclide` package. I try to run this:

```
    \documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide,ifthen}

    \usetkzobj{all}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=1, ymin=-1,ymax=1]
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
    \tkzDefPoint(.3,.5){A}\tkzDefPoint(.5,.2){B}\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzFindAngle(A,O,B)\tkzGetAngle{hoek}
    \ifthenelse{\hoek<180}{\tkzDrawArc(O,A)(B);}{\tkzDrawArc(O,B)(A);};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

I get the following error message:

```
! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
               .
l.12 \ifthenelse{\hoek<180}
                                 {\tkzDrawArc(O,A)(B);}{\tkzDrawArc(O,B)...

? H
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.
```

What I want a code that always draws the same arc between A and B, i.e. either the short one or the long one. Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you add `\show\hoek` just before the test tex will stop and show you

```
> \hoek=macro:
->-37.234850000000000000.
```

`\ifnum` (which is what `\ifthenelse` uses for numeric tests) is designed for tex numbers, which are integers.

So here it complains at the `.`

The usual TeX trick is to use dimensions to hold non integer values

```
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\hoek pt<180pt}}{\tkzDrawArc(O,A)(B);}{\tkzDrawArc(O,B)(A);};
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
\documentclass{article} 
    \usepackage{tkz-euclide,ifthen}

    \usetkzobj{all}
    \begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
    \tkzInit[xmin=-1,xmax=1, ymin=-1,ymax=1]
    \draw (0,0) circle [radius=1];
    \tkzDefPoint(.3,.5){A}\tkzDefPoint(.5,.2){B}\tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDrawPoints(A,B)
    \tkzFindAngle(A,O,B)\tkzGetAngle{hoek}
    \draw(0,0) node{\hoek};
    \pgfmathparse{(\hoek<180) ? 1 : 0 }
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfmathresult}{1}}{\tkzDrawArc(O,A)(B);}{\tkzDrawArc(O,B)(A);}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```